# test if ip is in use without ICMP

Tags: networking, automation, ping, icmp, nmap

I have an automated process of creating VMs on the network and before it checks if the IP that is used was not allocated by another server, so I need to do a test if the IP is in use;
It occurs that I have in my network some servers that are with active firewall and blocking ICMP Echo Request;
By internal security rules I can not use scanner software like nmap;
Is there any way to check if an IP is in use without using an ICMP (Ping) protocol or a port scan application?

Comment: You can use ARP. See _[RFC 5227, IPv4 Address Conflict Detection](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5227)_.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried arping? I thought no firewall would block arp.

Comment: It works if my process orchestrator is a Linux, but when is Windows? Is there any arp ping windows?